# Unresolved reference: newInstance?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am following kotlin guide. And I have an error name like this "

> "Unresolved reference: newInstance"

How can I fix it?

It's my code in android studio.

```
inner class PagerAdapter : FragmentStateAdapter {
        constructor(fm: FragmentManager, lc: Lifecycle) : super(fm, lc)

        override fun getItemCount() = 3

        override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
            var imageId:Int = 0
            var title:String = ""
            var details1:String = ""
            var details2:String = ""
            var fragment:PageFragment? = null

            when(position) {
                0 -> {
                    imageId = R.drawable.poster1
                    title = "${position+1}. name"
                    details1 = "312,745"
                    details2 = "15"

                    fragment = PageFragment.newInstance(imageId, title, details1, details2)
                }
                1 -> {
                    imageId = R.drawable.poster2
                    title = "${position+1}. name"
                    details1 = "166,604"
                    details2 = "15"

                    fragment = PageFragment.newInstance(imageId, title, details1, details2)
                }
                2 -> {
                    imageId = R.drawable.poster3
                    title = "${position+1}. name"
                    details1 = "51,608"
                    details2 = "12"

                    fragment = PageFragment.newInstance(imageId, title, details1, details2)
                }
                else -> {
                    fragment = PageFragment.newInstance(0, "", "", "")
                }
            }

            return fragment
        }
    }
```

It's red on all 'newInstance'.

Did 'newInstance' disappeared as the version changed?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Android, but PageFragment does not seem to stem from the official Android SDK, does it? Have you declared it on your own? Where do you import it from?

Comment: Yes! I have declared PageFragment

Comment: Then you might've deleted the function `newInstance` somehow? Or it might be inaccessible due to being private?

Comment: Are you able to post your code for `PageFragment` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the comments, `PageFragment` is [not part of the official Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/s/results?q=pagefragment), but rather something you or your colleagues have written yourselves.

Maybe one of your colleagues replaced the function in there, but without seeing the source code for `PageFragment` we're unable to help.

---

Just a quick hint, you can get rid of your `var` declarations inside `createFragment` by turning the whole function into an expression, e.g.:

```kotlin
override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    return when (position) {
        0 -> PageFragment.newInstance(
            imageId = R.drawable.poster1,
            title = "${position + 1}. name",
            details1 = "312,745",
            details2 = "15",
        )
        1 -> PageFragment.newInstance(
            imageId = R.drawable.poster2,
            title = "${position + 1}. name",
            details1 = "166,604",
            details2 = "15",
        )
        2 -> PageFragment.newInstance(
            imageId =R.drawable.poster3,
            title = "${position + 1}. name",
            details1 = "51,608",
            details2 = "12",
        )
        else -> PageFragment.newInstance(0, "", "", "")
    }
}
```

Comment: Were can I find newInstance code?

I will check if I had delelted it!

Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Are you able to share your code for `PageFragment` inside your question?

Comment: If I wirte my code at my question it say "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: Oh okay. That seems to be restriction enforced by StackOverflow then. Are you able to share the project (or the relevant parts of it) on GitHub (or a similar Code hosting platform)?

Comment: `newInstance()` should be defined in a companion object inside PageFragment. It should be responsible for creating a PageFragment instance by calling its constructor, adding the other parameters to its extras bundle, and then returning it.

Comment: Oh!!! sorry for bothering you! It was my typo. Thanks